# meaning of 名種設定?

Tags: compounds

A friend of mine asked me to give him a quick translation of an app he downloaded.
One of the buttons in the main menu had this 名種設定 written. I wasn't able to find what it means.

Comment: @cypher - How exactly is a question abot a word that is more then likely to be encountered in more then one application in Japanese, but still have no immidiate dictionary translation too localized? How can a question about a word in Japanese can even be too localized for a site that it's only goal is to answer questions about Japanese?

Comment: I've asked a question about this on [meta](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/987/how-do-we-draw-the-line-at-what-makes-an-on-or-off-topic-translation-question)

Comment: I've deleted my comments on this thread and voted to reopen as a similar question was asked at http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11247 today, and I think this a more common problem than I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have confused 名種設定 for [各種設定](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%90%84%E7%A8%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A), or "various settings".

Comment: yep, that's it.

Comment: @cypher san Ah! I couldn't recognize the difference, I was staring at this post for a minute or two. lol~~