# Is there a difference between 名国 and 国?

Tags: translation, kanji

I'm attempting a translation of a video game manual, and it keeps using compounds like 名国 and 名街. This is not a game where you're able to name the places/characters, and the sentences where the words appear are talking about the places themselves, not the names of them. Has anyone seen this before or have an idea on what it means?

Comment: I do not think that either 名国 or 名街 is a word in Japanese, and I suspect the possibility that the manual is either in Chinese or in broken Japanese.  What are some sentences which include words 名国 and 名街?  In some context (such as in word 名店), prefix 名 means “famous,” but I have never seen either 名国 or 名街 used with this meaning in Japanese.

Comment: @Var Or perhaps you are misreading 各国 and 各街.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: That sounds much more plausible!  And I should have thought of it, given that there was one question on this website where the asker misread 各種 as 名種.